# How do I rsync specific folders only

Tags: rsync

I want to rsync only selected folders from within a directory to a remote server.

The folders are listed in files.txt

```
user1/
user2/

rsync --dry-run -avv --include-from '/home/files.txt' /home/ -e ssh root@server:/home
```

This seems to work, however it scans through every single file on the source `/home`. This is a bit of a problem as there are millions of files and take days.

I tried using

```
rsync --dry-run -avv --include-from '/home/files.txt' --exclude='*' /home/ -e ssh root@server:/home
```

which didn't work as it just excluded everything.

Answer (score 1):

I personnaly prefer using a configuration file for `rsync` instead of a sometimes very long command line. Here is what i would do in your place using SSH as you did but with pubkey authentication :

My configuration file looks like this (`rsync.conf`, on server side):

```
uid = 0  # root uid
gid = 0  # root uid
use chroot = true
read only = true
hosts allow = a.b.c.d # Client IP address (SSH authentication lets the access to 
SSH server, here is extra-protection for the rsync server)
hosts deny = 0.0.0.0  # Others IP addresses are denied

[$module]
   path = /
   include /etc/*** /usr/bin/tools/***
   exclude /*** /usr/ /usr/bin/***
   filter = - .*
```

The command line would be (on client side):

```
rsync \
   --delete \  # Delete on destination files which does not exists on source
   -avz \      # -z:compress data during transfer; -a:archive; -v:verbose
   -e "ssh -i ~$USER/.ssh/$PRIVATE_KEY" \
   ${server}::${module} ${CLIENT_SIDE_DESTINATION}
```

On server, an SSH public key must be added in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. This key  will be `tagged` in order to only perform the synchronization through SSH:

```
from="a.b.c.d",command="rsync --server --daemon --config rsync.conf ." ssh-dss ....
```

This configuration would synchronize only `/etc/` and `/usr/bin/tools` folders; `filters` instruction will prevent hidden files to be synchronized as well. The tricky part is to adjust the `include` and `exclude` directives such as only your targeted folders would be synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying /home as the source directory which is slowing things down.Could you not have one job per user directory instead?

If this is impractical, then you could try reducing the overhead in comparing the files by using the  `--size-only`  flag, which will transfer files based file size omitting timestamp checks. This of course could produce undesirable behaviour, depending on your environment.

Other than that, the frequency at which rsync is run could improve things. Consider using [lsync](https://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/)
which will cause a sync to occur based on inotify events

Comment: I've been given 200+ folders to move. I guess I could rsync them manually but it will take awhile..

Comment: Try an initial sync first, then use lsyncd to sync subsequent changes. Sometimes it's more practical to physically take a copy of the data to the target server if it's not on the same site.